# Trying to hide a paragraph tag using jQuery addClass when an inline html onclick is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a paragraph tag using jQuery addClass when an inline html onclick is clicked, however it does not seem to be working, any suggestions?

```
<head>

     .remove {

        display: none;

     }

</head> 

<body>

           <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&rsaquo;</a>

           <P class="fade1">Where Innovation</P>


<script type="text/javascript">


        $(".next").click (function () {

                 $(".fade1").addClass("remove");

         });
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: The CSS needs to go in a `<style>` element, not directly in the `<head>` element.  You also need to include the jQuery library in order to use it.  You also have an errant `onclick="plusSlides(1)"` which doesn't make sense if you're using jQuery anyway *and* don't have that function defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(".next").click(function(){
  $(".fade1").addClass("remove");
});
```

```css
.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="next">&rsaquo;</a>
<p class="fade1">Where Innovation</p>
```

If you prefer *jQuery* over *JavaScript* then you always have to include its library in order to use it, otherwise it won't work. Here I am using *jQuery CDN (Content Delivery Network)* of version *2.1.1*.

But you can also download it (production or development / compressed or uncompressed) and reference it with the `<script>` tag usually as:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Where `js` is a typical folder name where you keep all of your *jQuery/JavaScript* files, `jquery-2.1.1.min` is a file name with the information about the used version and `.js` as a necessary file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide(1000);
    });
});
</script>



<button>Hide</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
```